# Accessing a PyQT widget outside it's class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, pyqt, qtextedit

a simple situation is proving fairly tricky.

My target is to get a window to update the status of a widget in another window.
To explain:

I have window A with some "data" and I want it written into the textEdit widget of window B. The specifics of the main window and the widgets are

```
class MainWin(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1127, 880)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 1081, 661))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.textEdit.isUndoRedoEnabled ()
```

What I am currently failing at obtaining is a simple method which called from another window (and another file) could change the content inside the textEdit.
Not sure what I am doing wrong, but when I do try to import the class or a method from the class I always seem to have issue with the

> TypeError: unbound method updEdit() must be called with
>   MainWin instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I am very much open to suggestions, and thanks in advance!

**Edit #1**

from file Rep.py (the second window I am simply calling)

```
def addTemplate(self):
        data = self.textBrowser.toPlainText()
        MainWin.MainWin.addText(MainWindow.MainWin,data)
        self.close()
```

From the first window, all I would need to do is:

```
def addText(self,data):
    self.textEdit.setText(data)
```

I am fairly new to OOP so please forgive me if there's some rather stupid mistake.

Comment: Add a method to your class that sets the text then call it from wherever you want.

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to call this method. Probably you're trying to call it on the MainWin class instead of on an instance of that.

Comment: Updated, probably I am doing the mistake you have mentioned but I am not sure on how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

When you create the second window, pass in a reference to the first window and store it as an attribute:

```
class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, firstwindow, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.firstwindow = firstwindow
        ...            

    def addTemplate(self):
        data = self.textBrowser.toPlainText()
        self.firstwindow.addText(data)
```

---

If the second window is a `QMainWindow` or `QDialog`, you could also make the first window the parent of the second window - in which case, there would be no need to store it as an attribute and you could just do:

```
        self.parent().addText(data)
```

Doing it this way also means the second window will automatically close when the first window closes.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but when I try to give the first window as arguement for the method, what I get is AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MainWindow' (which btw is the name of the first one).

What I am passing to the __init__ is mainWin.MainWindow. I have previously imported mainWin, however what comes to mid is that I might have a loop with imports as:

The second window is started from the first one, therefore I have imported into the first one. Also I need to edit the first window with the second one. Either way, thanks once more!