# Calling widgets from another class

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have two files made in `Qt Designer`, each one of them generates a window. When I press one button in `window_one`, `window_two` opens. In a third file I import the two classes and there I build the logic part of my application. But now I want to get information about widgets that are in the `window_one` and use it in `window_two`, but I don't know how to do it

```
from Window_ONE import window_one_ui
from Window_TWO import window_two_ui

class window_two(QtGui.QWidget, window_two_ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(window_two, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def AnyFunction(self)
        if self.QCheckBox.isChecked()==True #Here is the problem. 
            do somthing                     #QCheckBox was defined in the window_one_ui



class window_one(QtGui.QWidget, window_one_ui):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(window_one, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def Open_window_two(self):
        self.plotWindow = window_two()
        self.plotWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = window_one()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I call the variables from `windows_one`?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876329/984421).

Comment: How do I make the first window parent of the second?

Comment: As explained in that answer, the second window must be a `QMainWindow` or `QDialog` for that to work. It won't work with a plain `QWidget`, so you need to use the first method shown in the answer.

Comment: ok, thanks! I ended up changing it to a `MainWindow`, because I have many `widgets` that I want to call